# Using Autoprefixer with PostCSS - configure the browser support

Tags: node.js, postcss, autoprefixer

I am trying to add Autoprefixer into a Node.js script I have which compiles my SCSS files. On the [Autoprefixer docs on npm.js.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) they give the following code example for use with Node:

```js
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss      = require('postcss');
 
postcss([ autoprefixer ]).process(css).then(function (result) {
    result.warnings().forEach(function (warn) {
        console.warn(warn.toString());
    });
    console.log(result.css);
});
```

After implementing this my CSS is still returning without browser prefixes having been added. I believe this is because I have not passed in which browsers I wish to support. When I've used Autoprefixer in the past you have to pass a string such as 'last 2 versions' for this purpose. However I can't seem to find any documentation which shows how I can do this using Autoprefixer in this way. Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The currently recommended ways of [defining supported browser](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/tree/9.1.0#browsers) are:

- `.browserslistrc` config file in the project root
- `browserslist` field in project's `package.json` file

[`browsers` option](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/tree/9.1.0#options) is still supported, but it's use is discouraged:

```
postcss([ autoprefixer({ browsers:  'last 2 versions' }) ])
```